# How to bake an animation for a deformed mesh?

Tags: animation, modifiers, baking

I have made a mesh which is being shrinkwrapped onto a moving plane, which gives the effect of the mesh waving and moving. Problem is, I don't want the mesh to be dependent of the shrinkwrap modifier. How can I "bake" the animation so that the mesh can move on its own?

Comment: Why not? Is it because you don't want the shrinkwrap's target to be visible during render? It may be simpler to do something else than removing the modifier.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I want to give my mesh thickness, more specifically give it a round bevel (since it's a curve). But if I do this, the bevel will be flattened as well as the curve. Maybe another way to ask this question is: How can I have a curve with a bevel that is no affected by the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Modifier setup?